# Clase HtmlElement C# ¿Cómo puedo obtener todos los elementos con el mismo atributo de un HTML?

Tags: html, c#

estoy trabajando con la Clase HtmlElement de C# en la cual obtengo distintos atributos por medio del Método GetAttribute y mostrarlos en un TextArea. Si pongo el atributo de un atributo HTML general (En donde se encuentra todo el texto), me trae todos los elementos (que es lo que quiero), sin embargo se ve el texto todo junto.

```
readonly WebBrowser nav = new();

private void FormSynGen_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   nav.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
   nav.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(this.DataLoad);
}

private void DataLoad(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   foreach (HtmlElement item in nav.Document.All)
   {
      //Atributo general para traer todo el texto
      if (item.GetAttribute("classname").Contains("credits-scroller"))
      {
         //Se imprime en el TextArea
         RtxbReparto.Text = item.InnerText;
      }
   }
}
```

[Resultado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ES0Ei.png)

Me gustaría separar cada elemento por comas, de la siguiente forma.
[Resultado deseado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqazE.png)

Por otro lado, si pongo el atributo individual me trae solo el último texto que encuentra en el HTML.

```
foreach (HtmlElement item in nav.Document.All)
{
   //Atributo específico para traer texto individual
   if (item.GetAttribute("itemprop").Contains("name"))
   {
      //Se imprime en el TextArea
      RtxbReparto.Text = item.InnerText;
   }
}
```

[Resultado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qLQp.png)

¿Hay posibilidad de traer los elementos de forma individual en una especie de arreglo para poder separarlos con una coma?

Este sería un ejemplo del HTML que estoy leyendo.

```
<ul class="credits-scroller">
   <li>
      <a itemprop="url" href="#" title="Colin Farrell" tabindex="0"><img width="80" height="120" src="#"><div class="name" itemprop="name">Colin Farrell</div></a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a itemprop="url" href="#" title="Brendan Gleeson" tabindex="0"><img width="80" height="120" src="#"><div class="name" itemprop="name">Brendan Gleeson</div></a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a itemprop="url" href="#" title="Kerry Condon" tabindex="0"><img width="80" height="120" src="#"><div class="name" itemprop="name">Kerry Condon</div></a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a itemprop="url" href="#" title="Barry Keoghan" tabindex="0"><img width="80" height="120" src="#"><div class="name" itemprop="name">Barry Keoghan</div></a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a itemprop="url" href="#" title="Pat Shortt" tabindex="0"><img width="80" height="120" src="#"><div class="name" itemprop="name">Pat Shortt</div></a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ya usted esta obteniendo los elementos de forma separada en el  objeto: `item.InnerText` a partir de ahí puede guardarlo en un arreglo o simplemente agregarle una coma al final en el foreach cuando se lo asigna a `RtxbReparto.Text`  no ????. Le recomiendo usar expresiones regulares en lugar de hacer validaciones con `Contains()`

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario @RichardVíquezPérez. Al asignar `item.InnerText` a `RtxbReparto.Text` lo asigna como una cadena de texto, no como elementos por separado o un arreglo, por lo que si agrego la coma al finalizar el foreach, lo imprime al final de toda la cadena, no por separado, esto con el atributo general (primer bloque de código), con el individual, solo imprime el último elemento que encuentra de dicho atributo.

Comment: En ese caso ya intento el split(' ') ?? Eso le va a dividir la cadena por espacios en un arreglo de string sin embargo es mejor hacerlo con expresiones regulares insisto

Comment: Te recomendaria que mires un componente para "parsear" el HTML que sea mas facil de navegar como [AngleSharp](https://anglesharp.github.io/), muy facil y ponente. Pero no se si puedes utlizarlo... ¿ o si? Mira [un ejemplo](https://anglesharp.github.io/docs/core/03-Examples)

Comment: Debes colocar, al menos, un ejemplo del HTML a leer

Comment: Hola @Yussef, agregue un ejemplo del HTML que estoy leyendo, me interesa recuperar el texto dentro de la etiqueta  `<a>`, específicamente lo que se encuentra en el `<div>` con el atributo `itemprop="name"`, todos estos por separado dentro de un arreglo o algo similar para añadirles una coma al hacer el foreach y mostrarlos en el `TextArea`.

Comment: Gracias @JoseA.Fernandez, voy a darle una leída a la documentación.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te coloca el último código, porque en cada iteración que encuentra un elemento pisa el que encontró anteriormente

```
foreach (HtmlElement item in nav.Document.All)
{
   //Atributo específico para traer texto individual
   if (item.GetAttribute("itemprop").Contains("name"))
   {
      RtxbReparto.Text = item.InnerText; //Acá coloca el string en el TextArea
      //pero si en una siguiente iteración, encuentra otro elemento, pisa su valor
   }
}
```

Debes guardar los elementos en una lista y despues unirlos

```
List<string> lista = new();
foreach (HtmlElement item in nav.Document.All)
{
   if (item.GetAttribute("itemprop").Contains("name"))
   {
      lista.Add(item.InnerText);
   }
}
RtxbReparto.Text = string.Join(", ", lista); //unes la lista
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Yussef, justo declarar la lista era lo que me faltaba. Saludos.